# How to use sed and cat to add multi lines from one file to another

Tags: bash, shell, sed, cat

How can I use a `cat` and `sed` to read data from a file and insert it into another file under known line?

For example I have a file named `script1.txt` that contains a few hundred lines, one of the line has the value `"COMMANDS="commands"`

If I wanted use `sed` to insert a line under it, simply I can use `sed` as the command bellow.

```
sed -i '/^COMMANDS=.*/a NEW LINE HERE' script1.txt
```

But if I want to insert a multi lines and these lines inside a file, and these line changes every a few hours.. how can i do that ?

I tried:

```
DATA=$(cat data.txt)

sed -i '/^COMMANDS=.*/a '$DATA'' script1.txt
```

I got the error bellow.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

Is there a way other than `sed` to insert the data from file under known line with no issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^COMMANDS=/r dataFile' file
```

This will append the contents of the file `dataFile` after the line beginning `COMMANDS=` and update `file`

Answer (score 1):

If the data you want to append is multi-line, you might want to replace newlines with `\n`.

```
#!/bin/sh
DATA="$(awk '{gsub(/[]\/$*.^&[]/, "\\\\&");printf (FNR>1)?"\\n%s":"%s",$0}END{print ""}' data.txt)"
sed -i -e '/^COMMANDS=.*/a\' -e "$DATA" script1.txt
```

Here the `awk` command escapes `sed` special characters (for basic regular expressions), then prints `"%s"` for the first line, and `"\\n%s"` for the others. A newline is printed at the end, but it's somewhat pointless as `$()` strips it anyway.

The `sed` command is almost the same but multiple expressions are used which is equivalent to a multi-line sed script (The `a text` `sed` alternative syntax can act weirdly with leading spaces/backslashes).

Comment: i'll give it a try later. Thank you